# Image over text concept . I face some errors

Tags: css

```
          I face some problem during implementing image hover text concept . I am a beginner and i dont know much about it to implement . I copied my CSS code to stylesheet.css
```

The CSS code and HTML code i use is : http://jsfiddle.net/wzjxD/

This CSS code works fine but when i implement it it does not look good .

I need to implement this CSS code into the HTML code here : http://jsfiddle.net/hWA9h/

I need to implement that image hover text efect in this table . Please someone help me out and gimme a solved code .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Questions concerning problems with code you've written must **describe the specific problem** — and **include valid code** to reproduce it — in the question itself. See [SSCCE.org](http://sscce.org/) for guidance.

Comment: I guess the first link is just an example and the second link is his/her html markup that need to have the css and hover effect.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you want. Everytime you hover on the image link, a text will appear. You may need to adjust the css to your needs.
[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/hWA9h/4/) is the link to your answer. please check it out.
Below is for those who want to see the codes here.

for your html, you have the following (I shorten it to just one row for neat and clean answer):

```
<center>
<table id="wrapper" border="2" style="dotted">
<tr>
   <td>
       <a href="http://couponsoff.in/stores/snapdeal-coupon-codes"><img src="http://www.ohmygod.in/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/snapdeal.jpg" /></a>
       <p class="text">This is a text</p>
   </td>
   <td>
       <a href="http://couponsoff.in/stores/snapdeal-coupon-codes"><img src="http://www.ohmygod.in/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/snapdeal.jpg" /></a>
       <p class="text">This is a text</p>
   </td>
   <td>
       <a href="http://couponsoff.in/stores/myntra-coupon-codes/"><img src="http://www.ohmygod.in/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/myntra.jpg"/></a>
       <p class="text">This is a text</p>
   </td>
   <td>
       <a href="http://couponsoff.in/stores/jabong-coupon-codes"><img src="http://www.ohmygod.in/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/jabong.jpg"/></a>
       <p class="text">This is a text</p>
   </td>
</tr>
</table>
</center>
```

For your css, you have the following:

```
#wrapper .text {
    position: relative;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.4);
    text-align: center;
    text-height: 0;
    color: white;
    font-size: 1em;
    visibility: hidden;
}

#wrapper a:hover + .text {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Edited: 
If you want to use Jquery,
then pls have a look at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/hWA9h/7/)

Comment: Really thanks a lot bro . but my need is not satisfied fully bro . I need that hover effect has to appear on the image .

I need like this which appears in MOST POPULAR STORES tab in this link : http://freecouponson.com/

Comment: Thats because they are using jquery but you are trying to achieve it using css.

Comment: read my updated answer on the link to get the result you want using jquery